# how to change button name

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, button

how to change button title from oldTitle to NewTitle on Click events iphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written the code that you can use on the click event of the button to change its title from oldTitle to NewTitle on Click and again cage the code from NewTitle to OldTitle on another click.

```
BOOL isOne;
-(void) buttonClicked
{
    if(!isOne)
    {
        [callsButton setTitle:@"NewTitle" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            isOne=YES;
    }
    else
    {
        [callsButton setTitle:@"OldTitle" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            isOne=NO;
    }
//YOUR STUFFS HERE
}
```

hAPPY cODING...

Comment: dats because you dont have enough points to vote.. no worries atleast you can tick the answer as correct if it has helped you..

Answer (score 1):

to change the title of the UIButton use below code...

```
[myButton setTitle:@"New Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```